# how to solve out of memory error in java in amazon ec2 server

Tags: amazon-ec2, java

can anyone explain about this error message? we are using IBM jre to run java application
Its occupying more space on the server.

```
JVMDUMP006I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" - please wait.
JVMDUMP006I Processing dump event "systhrow", detail "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" - please wait.
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using '/home/sathish/jetty6/heapdump.20110417.114115.18926.0001.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to /home/sathish/jetty6/heapdump.20110417.114115.18926.0001.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using '/home/sathish/jetty6/heapdump.20110417.114115.18926.0002.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to /home/sathish/jetty6/heapdump.20110417.114115.18926.0002.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Heap dump using '/home/sathish/jetty6/heapdump.20110417.114115.18926.0003.phd' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Heap dump written to /home/sathish/jetty6/heapdump.20110417.114115.18926.0003.phd
JVMDUMP032I JVM requested Java dump using '/home/sathish/jetty6/javacore.20110417.114115.18926.0004.txt' in response to an event
JVMDUMP010I Java dump written to /home/sathish/jetty6/javacore.20110417.114115.18926.0004.txt
```

Comment: Give it more memory?

Comment: Thanks. we have given the heap size memory -Xms3000M -Xmx3000M, is that ok or do we need increase the memory? our RAM size is 7.6 GB.

Comment: Could indicate a memory leak (i.e. a bug in the application that causes it to keep memory/objects around that should not be kept).

Comment: You can increase the memory on the instance, I have a Jboss server running at -Xms2000M -Xmx6500M.  I opt for the lower -Xms because spawned processes will take that as their initial memory footprint.  It will cause issues if it is too high and you spawn sub processes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should enable JMX port on your JVM and run the Mission Control product to monitor the memory as your JVM runs.  Using Mission Control, you should be able to see what the problem is.